# pip version fail when building docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip

I am trying to create a docker image from my python application, but I get an error message about my pip version when trying to install :

```
Collecting tensorflow==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But when I check my pip version, it is the latest one:

```
pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

So why is docker linking to the wrong pip version?
I am running on Mac High Sierra.

Comment: Post your dockerfile. You are checking pip version on your host and not inside the the docker container

Comment: Adding 
    
    # Update pip
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip

to my Dockerfile fixed the problem.
Thx